# How can I insert java script file into webview after load a html

Tags: javascript, android, webview, local

I want to handle the click evnet on webview,and get the word which I click.
I researsh "BT Android WebView Selection",it calls method of java script in java code.
The html declare js file in ,and js file is large(>400k)

I want to open a network html like "www.google.com",when user click word on ths page,The java code will know what is the clicked word.

How can I insert the special js file and call the js's method of getting clicked text?

Comment: Could you please show us the code you have tried?

Comment: I research the code of https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection.git.